# String reversal using a single line of code in c

Tags: c, string

During a recent interview one of my friends was asked a question to reverse a string using only a single line of code.
The string is already stored in a `char*` variable.

I tried using recursion, but it never reduced to a single line of code.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: title says C, tag says C++. which is it?

Comment: Why would you not be able to put your recursive function into a single line of code?

Comment: As far as I know in C++ only preprocessor directives and sigle-line comments put any meaning to end of line. Everything else doesn't care. Which means you can write virtually any program in C++ on one line (assuming your compiler doesn't have any internal limitation on line length).

Comment: A variable of type `char` cannot hold a string. A string composed of 1 char is its own reverse :-)

Comment: Any other restraint? What do you mean by a 'single line'? It seems many common codes can be written in one line by using `,` operator (and end with a `;`).

Comment: @pmg : +1, because you exceeded the expectations by resolving the problem with ZERO lines... :-D

Comment: `for(int i=0,j=str.length()-1;i<str.length()/2;i++,j--)  str[i]^=str[j]^=str[i]^=str[j];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Write a program which works.
2. Condense it all onto a single line. You don't need to have linefeeds between statements!

Answer (score 5):

If you really want it in C, and `strlen` is allowed, this will work:

```
for( char *p = str, *q = str + strlen(str) - 1; p < q; *p ^= *q, *q ^= *p, *p++ ^= *q-- );
```

I do not recommend you to use this in any actual program... Anyone got an idea how to get rid of the `strlen`?

Edit: *even more beautiful*:

```
for( char *p = str, *q = strchr(str, 0) - 1, t; p < q; t = *p, *p++ = *q, *q++ = t );
```

Comment: Regarding `str + strlen(str) -1`: Use `strchr(str,0)-1`. Regarding that name `str`: Use something more meaningful, like `s`. And get rid of all those stupid spaces! This is an obfuscating question, so the answer should maximize obfuscation.

Comment: Remove the ugly xor. You can easily create a temp var at the same place you create your pointers.

Comment: The ability to declare variables in the initial segment of a for statement was introduced in later C standards (I want to say C99)

Answer (score 3):

```
char str[] = "test";

std::reverse(str, str + std::strlen(str));
```

Comment: +1. Elegant, easy to understand... As George says it: What else?

Comment: Nice, but OP has now retagged the question C (rather than C++).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine

```
void reverse(char *s, int len) { \
  if(len <= 1) \
    return; \
  char t; \
  char *e = s + len - 1; \
  while(s < e) { \
    t = *s; \
    *s = *e; \
    *e = t; \ 
    e--; \
    s++; \
  } \
}
```

Note that his code is all in one line. Prefer code clarity. If you can put a function's code into one line using language features, then use those features.

Comment: So there won't be any difference between 'multiple line' and 'single line' now... The question looks so meaningless?

Comment: @Stan I don't understand what you mean. Why is there no difference between them? "single line" is one single line. "multiple line[s]" are multiple lines. If you remove the line splice characters, you get multiple lines. Why would the question look meaningless?

Comment: Because all functions can be written into the single-line form by just using the `\\` in this sense... it wouldn't be the answer Joe needed, I guess :-)

Comment: @Stan depends on what the interviewer wants to hear. Perhaps he wanted to test whether he is aware of `\\`. I don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

It requires an ugly construct involving a while loop with character pointer arithmetic and both post-increment and post-decrement operators. Never, ever use such hideous code except in obfuscation contests. (No, not even in interviews. If they ask you such useless trivia, chances are they are equally clueless about other things.)